# Parse (the platform) maximum config parameters

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, config

I am designing an app that will make extensive use of the Parse Config parameters as a way to A/B test code changes without having to resubmit the app to the App/Play Stores.

Because Parse offers Objects for their parameters, I will be storing large data sets (like monster spawn stats) and game settings in these parameters.

I've checked the Parse website, the help docs, and the billing pages, but was unable to find the limits for number of parameters and size of parameters.

What are the limits on:

- Number of Config parameters per app
- Size of Config parameters (each individual parameter)
- Total size of Config parameters (all the parameter sizes combined)

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We currently allow up to 100 parameters in your config and a total size of 128KB across all parameters.

https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#config-parameters